# How to make a C++ project to copy its dependencies to the output folder?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have some libs that are used by my C++ Visual Studio project. But they aren't copied to the output folder. How to add this step to the build process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to project properties and use Custom Build Step or Build events. Just use command line commands. You can use macros to specify paths.

Comment: how can you ensure that the copied library is the same that is linked (so that you dont have to change the library path in various locations, but only one) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add external-projects on which your project depends to  **Project Properties->Common Properties->Framework and References**.

No copying of libraries needed.

You can also change the output path of your library-projects to a path that is found by the linker.

Answer (score -1):

If you need them to be copied, why not copy them manually?
If you need them to build your application, you just need to add their path in the AdditionalLibraryDirectories and the libraries themselves to the AdditionalDependencies.

Comment: Because ding stuff manually leads to mistakes. A build processes needs to be automated to be consistent and repeatable.

Answer (score -1):

You add a post-build step to do so.